# JavaScript Node assembling

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a function for rendering dom elements and I seem to be getting stuck with assembling more than one dom element before appending.

I've tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/RruyA/1/
And I can't seem to wrap my image with a link.

And using appendChild() where innerHTMl is now (marked with comment in the fiddle) produces an invalid pointer error.

I have a bunch of theories on what might be going wrong, but no solution yet. Help would rock!

Here's the full code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function tag (name, attributes, contents) {
      var tag = {};
      tag.name = name;
      tag.attributes = attributes;
      tag.contents = contents
      tag.create = function () {
        tag.element = document.createElement(tag.name);
        for (var prop in tag.attributes) {
          tag.element.setAttribute(prop, tag.attributes[prop]);
        }
        // This is the problem:
        tag.element.innerHTML = contents;
      }
      tag.render = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(tag.element);
      }
      return tag;
    }

    var p = tag('p', {'id':'details', 'class':'red nice lovely'}, 'Once upon a time in a golden castle on a silver cloud...');
    var img = tag('img', {'src':'http://miyazakihayao.blog.com/files/2010/05/castle-in-the-sky-x1.jpg', 'width': '200px', 'alt':'Golden Castle'});
    img.create();
    img.render();
    p.create();
    p.render();
    var a = tag('a', {'href':'http://google.com', 'target':'_blank'}, img.element);
    a.create();
    a.render();


}());
```

Comment: You shouldn't set a class name with `setAttribute`, use `node.className` instead: IE will choke on it.

Comment: Do you know which versions of IE will choke? I'm only supporting modern browsers for this project, meaning IE9 and up.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't test this lately and I don't have IE9. You know IE7 is still around, don't you? If you only support IE>=9, you're actually locking WinXP users out.

Comment: Yeah, I'm fine with that for this project. There's a ton of svg use and html5 video too, so it's all ECMAScript 5, makes my life easy : )

Comment: I think I found my answer with DOM Fragments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are attempting to add text and HTML elements in the same way.  Text will work fine with `innerHTML` although elements will be coerced to strings, and `appendChild` will add HTML elements, but you would need to wrap Strings in TextNodes.

So you can choose between those types and it works fine.

```
// This is a solution
if (contents) {
  if (contents instanceof HTMLElement) {
    tag.element.appendChild(contents);
  }
  else {
    tag.element.innerHTML = contents;
  }
}
```

Comment: You rock! I had tested for string at some point, but of course HTMLElements would test positive for string.